# Css not applying to Js 'document.write'

Tags: javascript, html, css

For some reason the css doesnt apply to this:

```
document.write('<p ' + 'class="' + txtClassName + '">' + txtValue + "</p>");
```

And when I go into inspect, it shows this:

```
<p class="txt">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit</p>
```

If I put that exact line into the original html file, the css works.

Anyone know why this is?

Comment: When exactly is the `document.write` executed?

Comment: Long story short: don't use `document.write()`.

Comment: I tested the code and it worked. Where is the ```document.write``` placed? I don't know if your scenario forces ```document.write``` but It's also a good idea to use the addClass method of jQuery.

Comment: @Ivar Thx, I now just change the innerHTML of a div. And it works now :)